# Combining ASP.NET API, Redis, and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api, redis

I have a search service which uses ASP.NET API and Elasticsearch. So ES to index data from a database for read purspose and the database if for the write. Now given user will request searches via ASP.NET API which call ES to provided the data. I would like add redis to cache the query request from the ASP.NET, is this still appicable? Or I dont need Redis on this?

The motivation for this is because since I'm using Elastic cloud and the rest of my backend services is in AWS I would like to cut down the cost of NAT data transfer by lessen calling the outside service and use internal service like Redis so this all within a VPC since backend services are in private network.